# Как создать и запускать   Multi-Mechanize проект из Eclipse (PyDev) ?

Tags: python, eclipse

Как создать и запускать  Multi-Mechanize http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/index.html# проект из Eclipse (PyDev) ?
 В документации есть только описание запуска и создания проекта через консоль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создаете проект через консоль. 
создаете пустой проект в eclipes.
импортируете файлы созданного проекта в пустой проект eclipse.

Comment: А запускать из Eclipse как?